# Using vector as output buffer?

Tags: c++, vector, buffer

I'm having a fairly *large* amount of data (>1MB) encoded in Base64.

I found a nice [library](https://github.com/aklomp/base64) which can help me dealing with this as fast as possible.

It's decode syntax is here, very basic, it needs an output buffer:

```
int base64_decode
    ( const char  *src
    , size_t       srclen
    , char        *out
    , size_t      *outlen
    , int          flags
    ) ;
```

Although I could have the output buffer from their sample:

```
char out[1*1024*1024];
```

But input size is **not** constant, and it somehow looks and feels bad to ask this much size at compile time. On the other hand, having a nice large buffer on stack shall give some speed advantages over data stored and accessed on heap ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24057331/is-accessing-data-in-the-heap-faster-than-from-the-stack)).

But I thought of using a `vector<char>` instead. I could define it as

```
std::vector<char> out;
```

Then when I have the input size, I can `resize` it:

```
out.resize(input_size);
```

Resizing would initialize all its items to 0, which seems impractical and unnecessary to me as the `base64_decode` would also initialize those items in the next step.

Therefore, `resize` might be not the best, but calling `reserve` will not help either as it doesn't modify the vector's size (although it doesn't initialize the items either).

As I have no prior information on the data size, I either need to use some runtime-resizable buffer, or take a big guess and allocate a huge buffer.

As the library is able to decode really fast, I would like to use the fastest solution for the output buffer too, and both `char array` and `vector` seems inappropriate. What could be the my fastest option then?

Comment: `resize` is probably going to be your fastest solution.  It's pretty easy for the CPU to zero out a `char`.  My advice, use `vector` and then profile.  If the performance is good, then your done.  If it's not, then you at least have data you can use to help chose a better solution.

Comment: Doesn't `base64_decode` return the amount of bytes it was able to decode? Then you invoke it continuously until it returns 0, meaning all data has been decoded. Using a too-large buffer (>1MB) is bad for cpu cache. But it's also easy to predict Base64 decoded size (is ~input*3/4+4 basically).

Comment: No, it doesn't return with decoded size, it's putting it into `outlen`. About size estimation yes, I it's not difficult once we have the input data's length.

Comment: Your stack array is only going to consume memory for the duration of the function call you are placing it in. And it is zero overhead to allocate/deallocate and initialize. A `std::vector`is going to be fairly slow to allocate/deallocate.

Comment: So I should do `char buffer[input_size]` right in front of `base64_decode`?

Comment: That's not legal `C++`. The size must be a compile time constant. You could make the buffer a reasonable size and do the conversion in chunks if necessary.

Comment: You can allocate uninitialized memory with `::operator new (input_size)` which is basically syntax sugar for `malloc`. But then writing to it for the first time will be much slower, because virtual memory pages are allocated on first access. It may be better to pre-allocate a fixed buffer at program startup instead and not worry about the zero-filling overhead.

Comment: `char buffer[input_size]` is supported by GCC and clang, but isn't Standard C++.  Still, 1MB is a fair bit to put on the stack - bit rude.  BTW /- it's possible to have a `vector<X>` of `struct X { X() { } x(std::byte b) : b_{b} { } std::byte b_; };` - then vector resizing doesn't zero out the memory (due to the no-op default constructor / since C++11), but it's less convenient to access the data afterwards.  Still, the first thing I'd do is consider how the output will be used: if you can use the output in chunks, just decode a bit at a time into a smaller stack-allocated buffer, use, repeat.

Comment: Where is this data going after you have decoded it?

Comment: The Standard may require zero-initializing, but a reasonable compiler could spot the following write without an intervening read or mutex lock. Removing redundant writes is a pretty common optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Stack allocations are indeed a lot faster than heap allocations, but (1) you might not have 1MB of stack and more importantly (2) decoding 1MB of Base-64 text takes more time than the allocation itself, even with a fast library.

Note that Base-64 decoding is exactly a 4:3 ration, if rounded up. Hence if you know `srclen`, then `(srclen+3)/4*3` is the required `outlen`. The main reason why it's an out-parameter is for that rounding - the actual length might be one byte shorter.

Comment: So to conclude you're saying I'm pretty much good to go with the vector?

Comment: Yup. The main exception would be if you want to return the data as a `std::string`, in which case you'd want to decode directly into an object of that type. But that's still the same heap (aka `std::allocator`) as vector.