# Why overloading the [] operator in a class/struct makes it so slow to access an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

For studying purposes, I was trying to create my own array class.

So i just created a simple class with an array and overloaded the [] operator to access the elements in the class:

```
template <class T>
class Array
{
  private:
    T *arr;
    int size;

  public:
    Array(int arrSize)
    {
        this->arr = new T [arrSize];
        this->size = arrSize;
    }

    T& operator[](int pos)
    {
        return this->arr[pos];
    }
};
```

When I run a simple test to check how fast different containers access 1.000.000 of their elements, I usually get these results (in seconds):

MyArrayClass: 0.017294

C Array: 0.009943

std::array: 0.014728

std::vector: 0.013836

Why is C array so much faster than my class? Weren't they supposed to be equally fast? At least, I wasn't expecting my own class to take twice the time the c array takes, considering it uses the same principle to access the elements.

Code used to measure the time (timenow = std::chrono::system_clock::now()) :

```
auto ti = timenow, te=timenow;


Array<int> tst (1000000);
int tst2[1000000];
std::array<int, 1000000> tst3;
vector<int> tst4(1000000);
ArrayT tst5(1000000);

ti = timenow;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    tst[i] = 1;
}
te = timenow;

std::chrono::duration<float> et = te-ti;

cout << "MyArrayClass: " << et.count() << nl

ti = timenow;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    tst2[i] = 1;
}
te = timenow;

et = te-ti;

cout << "C Array: " << et.count() << nl

ti = timenow;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    tst3[i] = 1;
}
te = timenow;

et = te-ti;

cout << "std::array: " << et.count() << nl

ti = timenow;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    tst4[i] = i;
}
te = timenow;

et = te-ti;

cout << "std::vector: " << et.count() << nl
```

Comment: Did you compile this with or without optimizations?

Comment: "Weren't they supposed to be equally fast?" Based on what logic? I assume you have some ideas about what does or doesn't cause overhead in C++, but where do those ideas come from? What did they tell you about the specific conditions required to make "zero-overhead" things actually zero overhead?

Comment: What are `ArrayT` and `tst5``. They seems unused.

Comment: It is slower because it is executing your code instead of the single instruction that is required to fetch an element from a real array.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the numbers you gave are for runs built with optimizations on.

There are different reasons why the custom `Array` may be slower than the built-in one. One remark I'd make, is that the custom array uses heap memory, while the built-in is on the stack. For more info on this topic, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24057744/939050).

Another idea would be to look at generated assembly on smth. like godbolt.com, and compare the instructions.

Also, note that your example is leaking memory - you allocate in constructor but never deallocate that memory.